# xcode 9 Objective-C Warning with UIWebView - Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, warnings

In Xcode 9, I'm getting this warning when i pass "nil" to UIWebView.

```
Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
```

when i do this code:-

```
[webFileView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
```

check this image:-

[image: check this image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @trungduc my question is how to remove this warning...??